# SELECT AS to all of the table

Tags: sql

I have a table with many columns and I want to add to each column the same prefix when doing select, I mean instead of long code:

```
SELECT table.id    AS prefix_id
      ,table.value AS prefix_value
      ,table.content AS prefix_content
      , ...
```

There is a simple way to do it?

Comment: Which rdbms? Dynamic sql might be an option (ie EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in the Oracle world).

Comment: Without knowing the database, the most anyone can say is to use dynamic SQL to iterate over the columns in order to construct the aliases you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to add a prefix to all columns, unless you do it manually using `AS` (like in your example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help you, write a script that does that. You can customize it to pass the table name, prefix etc

```
declare 
@tableName varchar(50) = 'school',
@sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT '

Select @sql = @sql+'c.'+c.name+',' from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = @tableName

--MORE PRECISELY
Select @sql = @sql+'c.'+c.name+' as prefix_'+c.name+', ' from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = @tableName

Set @sql = @sql + ' FROM '+@tableName+' c'

print @sql
```

Output, where `c.` is the prefix. You can modify the code to taste

```
SELECT c.SchoolID as prefix_SchoolID, 

    c.SchoolName as prefix_SchoolName, 
    c.Address as prefix_Address, 
    c.City as prefix_City, 
    c.State as prefix_State, 
    c.Country as prefix_Country,
    c.PhoneNumber as prefix_PhoneNumber, 
    c.Password as prefix_Password,
    c.CreatedBy as prefix_CreatedBy, 
    c.CreatedOn as prefix_CreatedOn, 
    c.ModifiedBy as prefix_ModifiedBy, 
    c.ModifiedOn as prefix_ModifiedOn, 

FROM school c
```

Notice the comma after `modifiedOn`. You may need to remove that from the `@sql` variable or manaually